# Getting error on Angular app: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting that error when I do I post from my controller

```
  function postDashboardsData (dataType, dateFrom, dateTo) {

    $scope[dataType + '_done'] = false;

    Api.post('rotations/' + vm.data[0]._id + '/dashboard', angular.extend({
        type : dataType,
        date_range : {
          from : dateFrom,
          to : dateTo
        }
      }, vm.data));
  }
```

and here I call that function in the same controller

```
  postDashboardsData('overall', $scope.datepickerConf1.overall, $scope.datepickerConf2.overall)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('data>>>', data);
      $scope.overallData = data;
    })
```

that then above is the one returning undefined

error again

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about `return` in your postDashboardsData:

```
function postDashboardsData (dataType, dateFrom, dateTo) {

    $scope[dataType + '_done'] = false;

    var dashboardsDataPromise = Api.post('rotations/' + vm.data[0]._id + '/dashboard', angular.extend({
        type : dataType,
        date_range : {
          from : dateFrom,
          to : dateTo
        }
    }, vm.data));

    return dashboardsDataPromise;
}
```

**Explanation**

Api.post() function returns a promise which is an object with `then` function. Your `postDashboardsData` function should return this promise, so return must be placed just before execution of Api.post.

Comment: what should I return ? `return vm.data` ?

Comment: Just look at the code I provided - 'return' is in the place where it should be ;)

Comment: If I am asking is because I don't have an idea. Sorry, but I don't get you. And in your code I don't see any return.

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: I get that, what I don't get is what should I put in the return.

Comment: I've edited the code. Maybe now you'll understand it a bit better :)

Comment: Just what I need and sorry, I am a junior dev starting my career.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `return` in `postDashboardsData` i.e.:

```
function postDashboardsData(dataType, dateFrom, dateTo) {

    $scope[dataType + '_done'] = false;

    return Api.post('rotations/' + vm.data[0]._id + '/dashboard', angular.extend({
        type: dataType,
        date_range: {
            from: dateFrom,
            to: dateTo
        }
    }, vm.data));
}
```

Then you can use `postDashboardsData` like so:

```
postDashboardsData(dataType, dateFrom, dateTo).then(function(response){
     console.log(response, response.data);
})
```

Comment: what should I return ? `return vm.data` ?

Comment: I've updated your code so that `postDashboardsData` returns a promise. This promise resolves to whathever `Api.post` gots from the server. Usually it's a `response` which has `data` property.